# Which one grows faster asymptotically: $\log(\log^an)$ or $\log^a(\log n)$

Tags: asymptotics

Could someone explain to me which function grows faster?

$f(n)=\log(\log^an)$ or $g(n)=\log^a(\log n)$

Comment: Does $\log^a x$ mean $(\log x)^a$ or "take the log of $x$, $a$ times"? What did you try? Where did you get stuck? Did you look at our [reference question](http://cs.stackexchange.com/q/824/9550)?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Assuming $\log^a n$ means $\log n$, raised to the power $a$:

Let $t = \log \log n$, then the first expression equals $t·a$, while the second expression equals $t^a$. For $a > 1$ the latter grows faster, for $a < 1$ the former is faster, and for $a = 1$ they are identical.